# How do I compare these two arrays?

Tags: c++

Basically, I have two arrays. One has the correct answers to a test and the other has the user answers to the test. How do I compare the two? For example:

How would I show the user scored 15-20 on the test?
How would I show how many questions the user got incorrect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUM_ANSWERS = 20;
    char answers[NUM_ANSWERS] = { 'A', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B' };
    char userAnswer[NUM_ANSWERS];
    string textName;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "\nEnter a text file name ";
    cin >> textName;
    ofstream textFileOut;
    textFileOut.open(textName);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ANSWERS; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the test answers ";
        cin >> userAnswer[i];

        textFileOut << userAnswer[i] << '\n';
    }
    textFileOut.close();

    ifstream textFileIn;
    textFileIn.open(textName);
    while (count < NUM_ANSWERS && textFileIn >> userAnswer[count])
        count++;

    textFileIn.close();

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Try comparing each element individually.

Comment: Your sample code has `for` loops. That's all you need to do what you are asking for. Where are you stuck?

Comment: How do I compare each element? I don't know how to go about comparing them like how would I compare the answers[NUM_ANSWERS] to the userAnswer[NUM_ANSWERS]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should take care of that for you. By using a counter you get the number of correct answers which, if all answers are worth the same, gets you at the same time, the number of incorrect answers and the user score.

```
numCorrect = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (userAnswer[i] == answers[i])
        numCorrect++;
}
```

Comment: Down voter, care to comment? Did I not understand the question correctly?

Comment: Do not know why it was donwvoted... Seemed perfectly reasonable and the right answer to me. I would also like to know why it was downvoted.

Comment: I do agree that Carey Gregory's answer is appropriate to the question.  A possible minor modification is that the number of incorrect answers is equal to `count - numCorrect`.

Comment: I thought I gave him the vote? His answer was right.

Comment: @Peter Actually, the number of incorrect answers is given by `NUM_ANSWERS - numCorrect`. That takes into account the possibility that the student left some questions unanswered.

Comment: @simplegamer You may have upvoted but you didn't accept the answer. You can accept it by clicking the checkmark.